# Displaying current default date in UIDatePickerr view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, datepicker

If I am selecting date from date picker view for current date, the time is also getting selected and displaying the current time, I want to separate in two different selection event

Here is my code snippet-

/* Button for displaying UIDatePicker view */

```
-(void) dueDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, yyyy"];


    self.lbl_StartDateValue.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
    self.planStartDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];

    NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]] options:0];

    self.lbl_EndDateValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"End %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
    self.planEndDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}

// Here I am not able to differentiate the selection of two picker view


-(void)onDoneButtonClick {

    [self dueDateChanged:self.picker];
    [self dueTimeChanged:self.picker];
    [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.picker removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tempBackgroundView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void) dueTimeChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    self.lbl_timeValue.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
    self.planAlarmtime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
}
```

Comment: Hm, that's weird. The default date should be selected by default. What happens when you try to select the current date in the picker?

Comment: @andlin, It is not displaying anything and if I select some other date it is working fine !!!

Comment: @Sudhir - if user does not change the datepicker you want to show the current date in the text field , correct or else

Comment: Are you saying that the date isn't even displayed in the datepicker?

Comment: If the problem is that the default date isn't displayed in the textfield initially, that's because dueDateChanged isn't called until the user actively selects a date. In this case you can manually call dueDateChanged after creating the datepicker.

Comment: @Anbu.karthik, Correct

Comment: @Sudhir - show that code of this `onDoneButtonClick`

Comment: @andlin, I want to display the current date if user select the current date in date picker!!!

Comment: @Anbu.karthik , -(void)onDoneButtonClick {
    [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.picker removeFromSuperview];
}

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in dueDateChanged? Is it hit when the current date is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like , initially set the current date on your text field whenever user present the date picker

```
  (IBAction)btn_calendar_event:(id)sender {
   ......
 [self.toolbar sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];
//if you want to show the default date as current date 

self.picker.date = [NSDate date];
 // set inital date on your textfield
[self dueDateChanged :  self.picker];
 }
```

if user pressed the done button then call this

```
-(void)onDoneButtonClick { 
 // call the method
[self dueDateChanged :  self.picker];
[self.toolbar removeFromSuperview]; 
[self.picker removeFromSuperview]; 
  [_txtf_birthDate resignFirstResponder];
}
```

finally change the YYYY format

```
-(void) dueDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender {

    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];


    NSLog(@"Picked the date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);
    _txtf_birthDate.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];

}
```

Comment: If I use time picker view at the same time, then in the done event If I set the date then time is also automatically getting set to current time. How to differentiate it?

Comment: -(void)onDoneButtonClick {
    
    [self dueDateChanged:self.picker];
    [self dueTimeChanged:self.picker];
    [self.toolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [self.picker removeFromSuperview];
    [self.tempBackgroundView removeFromSuperview];
}

Comment: I have another method named duetimechanged , and I call it in the same done event but If I set date the time is also automatically getting set to current time, I want to select it separately!

Answer (score 1):

Just set minimum data  as your current date

```
[self.picker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
```

also you will not select until you scroll Picker

if you want to show the default date as current date

```
self.picker.date = [NSDate date]
```

Answer (score 0):

## this is the code for UIDatepicker alloca and set current date

```
UIDatePicker *datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-320, self.view.frame.size.width, 320)];
datepicker.date = [NSDate date];
[self.view addSubview:datepicker];
```